# How to check out the entire solution from TFS?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, tfs

I've been checking my work to TFS. Now it seems like I've deleted the folder where was my solution. How can I get my work from TFS so that I can keep open it in Visual studio and keep working? I've just a local TFS.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Usually a "get latest" will do. However, if the TFS client thinks everything is peachy and refuses to actually put files on your disk, look for the "Get Advanced" option and check the checkboxes to force it to do something. Be aware that this latter option will happily overwrite files checked out **and changed** on disk with whatever was last checked in, effectively removing your changes so be sure you understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform "Get Latest Version" in Source Control Explorer to get project from TFS to your local machine. Then double click solution file, you'll see your solution opened in Solution Explorer.

[image]